# joomla shows all empty articles

Tags: joomla

Joomla is showing all empty articles, I have no idea why. Categories and front page works fine, but completely empty articles. How can I fix this? Website is http://ratroad.com
It has K2 installed, but it worked fine with it.

Comment: I figured out that I can see categories and frontpage normally, but I can't see anything at article

Comment: Did you enable or modify any plugins recently? If so I would go into the plugin manager and disable one by one to see if these are the cause, starting with content plugins.

Comment: Did you modify the k2 template or created yours ? Take a look at modules/plugins in that view.

Comment: Check the articles to see if they have data in them?  Last I remember K2 needs you to 'import' the articles into k2 from Joomla, doesn't it?  I can't remember specifically - but K2 caused me a good many headaches to the point I said forget it and went a different direction.  Double check the data actually exists - if it does?  Then start looking elsewhere.  Disable k2, does the data display?  If so - then it's specific to k2 and more troubleshooting in that direction is the answer.

Comment: there are only K2 articles on the website.

Comment: I found the problem. One unclosed <div> tag in template. Retarded K2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. One unclosed  tag in template. K2 template is not showing any error.